# Weird behaviour from Rspec Rails (Different outputs for the same test )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rspec-rails

I'm experiencing a very weird behaviour with my Rspec tests.

I have the following test to demonstrate the problem:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "RESTful API" do

  describe "Listing Entities" do

    context 'With valid Token' do

      before do
        entries = create_list(:entry, 10)
        admin   = create(:admin) 
        get api_entries_path, {token: admin.api_key.token}        
      end


      it 'Shows a list of entries' do     
        puts JSON.parse(response.body)
      end

      it "Should show no entries when the user has no data" do          
        puts JSON.parse(response.body) 
      end

    end

  end
end
```

The very weird behaviour is that I'm getting two different outputs while I'm supposed to have the exact same response. I'm getting the followings:

```
{"entries"=>[{"id"=>1, "user_id"=>1, "username"=>"admin", "distance"=>50.0, "time_period"=>60, "date_time"=>"2014-05-15 03:36:11 +0300", "created_at"=>"2014-05-15T01:54:40.000Z", "distance_type"=>"Km"}, {"id"=>2, "user_id"=>1, "username"=>"admin", "distance"=>50.0, "time_period"=>60, "date_time"=>"2014-05-15 03:36:11 +0300", "created_at"=>"2014-05-15T01:54:40.000Z", "distance_type"=>"Km"}, {"id"=>3, "user_id"=>1, "username"=>"admin", "distance"=>50.0, "time_period"=>60, "date_time"=>"2014-05-15 03:36:11 +0300", "created_at"=>"2014-05-15T01:54:40.000Z", "distance_type"=>"Km"}, {"id"=>4, "user_id"=>1, "username"=>"admin", "distance"=>50.0, "time_period"=>60, "date_time"=>"2014-05-15 03:36:11 +0300", "created_at"=>"2014-05-15T01:54:40.000Z", "distance_type"=>"Km"}, {"id"=>5, "user_id"=>1, "username"=>"admin", "distance"=>50.0, "time_period"=>60, "date_time"=>"2014-05-15 03:36:11 +0300", "created_at"=>"2014-05-15T01:54:40.000Z", "distance_type"=>"Km"}, {"id"=>6, "user_id"=>1, "username"=>"admin", "distance"=>50.0, "time_period"=>60, "date_time"=>"2014-05-15 03:36:11 +0300", "created_at"=>"2014-05-15T01:54:40.000Z", "distance_type"=>"Km"}, {"id"=>7, "user_id"=>1, "username"=>"admin", "distance"=>50.0, "time_period"=>60, "date_time"=>"2014-05-15 03:36:11 +0300", "created_at"=>"2014-05-15T01:54:40.000Z", "distance_type"=>"Km"}, {"id"=>8, "user_id"=>1, "username"=>"admin", "distance"=>50.0, "time_period"=>60, "date_time"=>"2014-05-15 03:36:11 +0300", "created_at"=>"2014-05-15T01:54:40.000Z", "distance_type"=>"Km"}, {"id"=>9, "user_id"=>1, "username"=>"admin", "distance"=>50.0, "time_period"=>60, "date_time"=>"2014-05-15 03:36:11 +0300", "created_at"=>"2014-05-15T01:54:40.000Z", "distance_type"=>"Km"}, {"id"=>10, "user_id"=>1, "username"=>"admin", "distance"=>50.0, "time_period"=>60, "date_time"=>"2014-05-15 03:36:11 +0300", "created_at"=>"2014-05-15T01:54:40.000Z", "distance_type"=>"Km"}], "total_count"=>10}

{"entries"=>[], "total_count"=>0}
```

As you can see I got two different outputs.

As for the User and ApiKey models:

```
# Controller 

class Api::V1::EntriesController < Api::V1::BaseController

  def index
    @entries = @current_user.entries    
  end

end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  # relationships 
  has_many :entries
  has_one :api_key, dependent: :destroy

  # Generate API Key to be useed with the API
  after_create :create_api_key

  private

  def create_api_key
    ApiKey.create!(:user_id => self.id)
  end  

end

class ApiKey < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    before_create :generate_token

    private

    def generate_token
      begin
        self.token = SecureRandom.hex.to_s
      end while self.class.exists?(token: token)
    end 
end
```

Please note that I have DatabaseCleaner as the following:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
  end

  config.before(:each, :js => true) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
  end

  config.before(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.start
  end

  config.after(:each) do
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
  end

end
```

Please note that I'm using ruby(2.0), rails (4.0.4) and rspec-rails(2.14.2). I'm using OS X 10.7.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a guess: Perhaps a DB problem creating the :admin object a second time?

Comment: Thanks for your willing to help, anyway I doubt it's related to DB as long i'm using FactoryGirl to create records. Please correct me if it's not the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling for hours it turned out that I had to change:

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
```

to :

```
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = : truncation
```

the truncation is resetting the id's back to 0 (well 1) where as transaction isn't, and I'm using a hard coded id in my factory.

Thanks for your help Jon Rowe.

Comment: So it was the DB after all (although I would never have spotted this specific problem)

Comment: yes, related to the DB and truncation strategy. But most of all it was for bad practice from me using hardcoded IDs in my Factories.